# php - htmlspecialchars with unicode

Tags: php

```
    $string = "Główny folder grafik<p>asd nc</p>";

echo htmlspecialchars($string);
```

on live site

```
G&#322;ówny folder grafik<p>asd nc</p>
```

on local

```
Główny folder grafik<p>asd nc</p>
```

what is problem ? i want when run on live site result look like local

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the first place? It shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

[**`htmlspecialchars()`**](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) accepts additional parameters -- the third one being the charset.

Try specifying that third parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add extra parameters to the htmlspecialchars() function. The following should work:

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to pass an optional parameter to [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) about charset which is ISO-8859-1 by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you require all strings that have associated named entities to be translated, use `htmlentities()` instead, that function is identical to `htmlspecialchars()` in all ways, except with `htmlentities()`, **all** characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities.

but even `htmlentities()` does not encode **all** unicode characters. It encodes what it can [all of latin1], and the others slip through (e.g. `Љ).

This function consults an ansii table to custom include/omit chars you want/don't.

(note: sure it's not that fast)

```
/**
 * Unicode-proof htmlentities.
 * Returns 'normal' chars as chars and weirdos as numeric html entites.
 * @param  string $str input string
 * @return string      encoded output
 */
function superentities( $str ){
    // get rid of existing entities else double-escape
    $str = html_entity_decode(stripslashes($str),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
    $ar = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $str );  // return array of every multi-byte character
    foreach ($ar as $c){
        $o = ord($c);
        if ( (strlen($c) > 1) || /* multi-byte [unicode] */
            ($o <32 || $o > 126) || /* <- control / latin weirdos -> */
            ($o >33 && $o < 40) ||/* quotes + ambersand */
            ($o >59 && $o < 63) /* html */
        ) {
            // convert to numeric entity
            $c = mb_encode_numericentity($c,array (0x0, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8');
        }
        $str2 .= $c;
    }
    return $str2;
}
```